# How to set Jboss Modeshape JNDI property

Tags: jboss, repository, jndi, modeshape

How can ı set jndi-name property on my local jboss modeshape repository named as a "sample"
I've just tried,
/subsystem=modeshape/repository=sample:add(jndi-name="jcr/sample") code but it fails

```
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => "JBAS014803: Duplicate resource [
    (\"subsystem\" => \"modeshape\"),
    (\"repository\" => \"sample\")
]",
    "rolled-back" => true
}
```

Comment: How does it fail? Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This CLI command

```
/subsystem=modeshape/repository=sample:add(jndi-name="jcr/sample")
```

will attempt to add a *repository* named "`sample`" with the given "`jndi-name`" attribute. The error message indicates that you already have an existing "sample" repository, so rather than add a repository you want to just update the "`jndi-name`" attribute on the "`sample`" repository. To do this, simply use this command:

```
/subsystem=modeshape/repository=sample:write-attribute(name=jndi-name,value="jcr/sample")
```

You can read the attribute with:

```
/subsystem=modeshape/repository=sample:read-attribute(name=jndi-name)
```

and you can read the description of the repository resource with:

```
/subsystem=modeshape/repository=sample:read-resoure
```

or of the repository resource and its children resources:

```
/subsystem=modeshape/repository=sample:read-resoure(recursive="true")
```